# Ultraweak Continuity Implies Norm Continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, completely-positive-maps

I was reading the section on Schur Multipliers in Ozawa's book "C*-algebras and Finite-Dimensional Approximations" and I am having troubles understanding the proof of Proposition D.6, namely the part about ultraweak continuity.

I think I can skip most of the context and I am stuck on a particular part, so I'll write it differently.

Let $H$ be a Hilbert (in the problem we have $H=\ell^2(\Gamma)$) and let $T: B(H) \rightarrow B(H)$ be an ultraweak continuous linear operator on $H$, moreover, we know that the restriction $T|_{K(H)}:K(H) \rightarrow K(H) $ is well defined and not only ultraweak continuous, but also norm continuous. To my understanding of the proof in the book, this implies that $T$ is also norm continuous on the whole $B(H)$, however I am not being able to prove this.

I tried using the fact that trace class operators (predual of $B(H)$) are compact, but did not reach any relevant conclusion, moreover I am almost sure the Uniform Boundness Theorem is required.

If this affirmation is false and more context is needed, it can be found in the mentioned book, Proposition D.6.

Comment: This is valid in a more general context. Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $S:Y^*\to X^*$ be linear. $S$ is weak$^*$-to-weak$^*$ continuous iff $\exists$ bounded $T:X\to Y$ such that $S=T^*$. Apply this to $X=Y=$trace class operators, and keep in mind that $X^*=B(H)$ and ultraweek topology is the weak$^*$ topology on $B(H)$.

Comment: @OnurOktay Yes this is very helpful and it is similar to what I was trying to do, It will be very good to keep this mind going foward thank you.

Comment: @OnurOktay However, I think this is not applicable in this specific case because we only know that $T|_{K(H)}:K(H) \rightarrow K(H)$ and we do not necessarily have $T|_{L^1(B(H))}:L^1(B(H)) \rightarrow L^1(B(H))$, only $T|_{L^1(B(H))}:L^1(B(H)) \rightarrow K(H)$ . Is there a way around this?

Comment: @TomásPacheco That’s not what Onur meant. What Onur’s comment suggested is that, more generally, if a linear map $T: Y^\ast \to X^\ast$ is weak$^\ast$-to-weak$^\ast$ continuous, *without any other assumptions whatsoever*, then it is automatically bounded, which can be proved via uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @DavidGao Ah! and thats because if $S: X \rightarrow Y$ is bounded and such that $S^* = T$ then $T$ is bounded right?

Comment: @TomásPacheco Well, if you proved $T = S^\ast$ and $S$ is bounded, then of course $T$ is bounded (with the same norm). The hard part here is using uniform boundedness principle to show such an $S$ is bounded in the first place.

Comment: @DavidGao Yes, I undestand now, something was feeling weird indeed. However I have one more bug on my head, is every weak*-to-weak* operator $T:Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ the adjoint of some $S:X \rightarrow Y$?

Comment: @TomásPacheco That was what I was actually talking about… I’ll add another answer as community wiki to elaborate.

Comment: @TomásPacheco I added the answer. I should point out though, that while Onur’s comment is more general, it is not sufficient for the proof of Proposition D.6 since that proposition talks about complete boundedness and also with the same cb-norm, both of which require precise control of the norm of $T$, namely that it is the same as its norm when restricted to $K(H)$. That can only be achieved via Kaplansky density.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m adding another answer, as community wiki, to expand upon @OnurOktay ’s comment:

**Claim:** If $T: X^\ast \to Y^\ast$ is weak$^\ast$-to-weak$^\ast$ continuous, where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces, then $T$ is bounded. In fact, there exists bounded $S: Y \to X$ s.t. $T = S^\ast$.

**Proof:** For each $y \in (Y)_1$, we let $T_y: X^\ast \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $T_y(\phi) = [T(\phi)](y)$. We observe that $T_y$ is bounded. Indeed, evaluation at $y$ is a weak$^\ast$ continuous linear functional on $Y^\ast$, so by weak$^\ast$-to-weak$^\ast$ continuity of $T$, $T_y$ is a weak$^\ast$ continuous linear functional on $X^\ast$, so it is given by evaluation at some $x \in X$ and thus in particular bounded.

Consider the collection of maps $\{T_y: y \in (Y)_1\}$. For each fixed $\phi \in X^\ast$, $|T_y(\phi)| = |[T(\phi)](y)| \leq \|T(\phi)\|$ since $\|y\| \leq 1$, i.e., $\sup_{y \in (Y)_1} |T_y(\phi)| < \infty$ for any fixed $\phi$. So by uniform boundedness principle, $\sup_{y \in (Y)_1, \phi \in (X^\ast)_1} |T_y(\phi)| < \infty$, but,

$$\sup_{y \in (Y)_1, \phi \in (X^\ast)_1} |T_y(\phi)| = \sup_{\phi \in (X^\ast)_1} \sup_{y \in (Y)_1} |[T(\phi)](y)| = \sup_{\phi \in (X^\ast)_1} \|T(\phi)\| = \|T\|$$

So $\|T\| < \infty$, i.e., $T$ is bounded.

Finally $S$ is simply defined as the adjoint of $T$ restricted to $Y \subset Y^{\ast\ast}$. As we have seen in the first paragraph of the proof, composing $T$ with evaluation at $y \in Y$ gives evaluation at some $S(y) \in X$. Since $S$ is a restriction of $T^\ast$ and $T$ is bounded, $S$ is bounded as well. That $T$ is the adjoint of $S$ follows easily from the definition. $\square$

Comment: I was quite close to proving this on my own, so $S$ isn't needed to prove that $T$ is bounded. I think I got it except one tiny thing. I am probably wrong but when you say that $T_y$ has to be an evaluation at some $x \in X$, isn't this the case only if $X$ is reflexive? And in case I haven't said it enough, thank you so much.

Comment: @TomásPacheco $T$, by assumption, is weak$^\ast$-to-weak$^\ast$ continuous. $T_y$ is $T$ composed with evaluation at $y$, which is weak$^\ast$ continuous, so $T_y$ is weak$^\ast$ continuous as well. The only weak$^\ast$ continuous linear functionals on $X^\ast$ are evaluation at some $x \in X$. This does not require any reflexivity assumptions. (It would require reflexivity if $T_y$ is just bounded, but here I’m saying it’s weak$^\ast$ continuous, which is a stronger condition.)

Comment: Ah, this is very subtle but I get it now, and allow me to say one last thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

By Kaplansky density theorem, for any $x \in B(H)$, there exists a net $x_\lambda \in K(H)$ with $x_\lambda \to x$ ultraweakly and $\|x_\lambda\| \leq \|x\|$ for all $\lambda$. Then $\|Tx_\lambda\| \leq \|T|_{K(H)}\|\|x_\lambda\| \leq \|T|_{K(H)}\|\|x\|$. By ultraweak continuity of $T$, we have $Tx_\lambda \to Tx$ ultraweakly, whence $\|Tx\| \leq \|T|_{K(H)}\|\|x\|$. Since $x \in B(H)$ is arbitrary, this means $T$ is bounded and in fact $\|T\| \leq \|T|_{K(H)}\|$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have a question, is it the case that $\|Tx_\lambda\| \rightarrow \|Tx\|$ ? If yes why does ultraweak convergence imply it? I am quite new into the ultraweak topology, do you recommend a reference where I can learn it more? Thank you so much for the reply

Comment: @TomásPacheco No, it is not true in general that $\|Tx_\lambda\| \to \|Tx\|$, but it is true that $\|Tx\| \leq \lim \sup \|Tx_\lambda\|$, which is enough to prove the claim.

Comment: @TomásPacheco I’m not sure if there’s any reference *specifically* on ultraweak topology, but most introductory textbooks on operator algebras cover this. See Chapter 4 of Murphy’s $C^\ast$-algebras and operator theory, and Chapters 2 and 3 of Conway’s A course in operator theory, for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the book recomendations, it was what I was looking for. Regarding the inequality, I am having troubles seeing where it comes from, do you have a hint? Thank you again

Comment: @TomásPacheco Use the definition of ultraweak convergence to prove the following: if $x_\lambda \to x$ ultraweakly and $x_\lambda$ are all in the unit ball, then $x$ is in the unit ball as well. Hint: $\|x\| = \sup_{\varphi \in (B(H)_\ast)_1} |\varphi(x)| = \sup_{\varphi \in (B(H)_\ast)_1} \lim_\lambda |\varphi(x_\lambda)|$.

Comment: Will try, thank you so much for your availability in this and the other thread.